# JPA table mapping in scala

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework

In my scala/play project I want to use JPA as persistent layer. But I got this...

```
The major disadvantage at the time is that scala up to versions 2.7.x does not support nested annotations, so you cannot use any of the JPA annotations that represent collections of related annotations (like @JoinColumns or @NamedQueries) or have a complex structure like @SqlResultSetMapping. But you can get quite far by designing you entity classes in a way that will give you sensible table definitions with the default naming conventions.
```

Source : http://www.hars.de/2009/03/jpa-with-scala.html

If it is true , How we can use JPA table mapping in Play with Scala?
Any Link with table mapping example in play-scala will be highly appreciated.

is there any other good alternative in play Scala other than JPA?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That link is utterly out of date and arguably incorrect with respect to many things that I can see there. No idea about Scala but why don't you just try it?

Comment: Did you try something like slick and anorm

Comment: @jijo do you know does anorm  support transaction? As per my knowledge Anorm doesn't provide a built-in way to handle database transactions. Actually we want migrate a REST web service application from java-spring-mybatis to play-scala. So I guess anorm is exact fit in our case. Your views please...